# Destroy specific users through terminal - ROR & Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, terminal

Ruby on Rails app using PG database on Heroku: Can I destroy specific users in the database through the terminal? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
heroku run console [--app=app_name]
```

Then run normal user find/destroy:

```
User.destroy(1)
```

This is safer than the pure-SQL approach as it runs callbacks, destroys relevant related objects, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that from the commandline via `heroku run rails db`, which will get you to the psql console.

From there it's just a `DELETE FROM USERS WHERE`... statement

Comment: (Offsetting the -1; it's a valid, if tricky-to-do-right way. If the data model is simple, this is find.)